# Unable to send Client's timestamp to the server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, timestamp, server

Please check the below code

**JSP**

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Sep 8, 2015, 10:13:49 AM
    Author     : Yohan
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.sql.Timestamp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

        <script>
            function time()
            {
                 var elem = document.getElementById("hiddenTxt");
                 elem.value = "<%= new Date().getTime()%>";
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
             function time2()
            {
                 var elem = document.getElementById("hiddenTxt");
                 elem.value = Date.now();
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
             function time3()
            {
                 alert(<%= new Date().getTime()%>);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="time3()" value="click" >Click</button>

        <form action="TimestampClass" method="post" onsubmit="time2()">
            Name: <input type="text" name="nameTxt">
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenTxt" id="hiddenTxt" >
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Servlet**

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
public class TimestampClass extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

//        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
//        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(currentTimeMillis);
//        System.out.println(currentTimeMillis);
//        System.out.println(timestamp);

        String name = request.getParameter("nameTxt");
        long timeStampLong = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("hiddenTxt"));

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(name);
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Script Time: "+getSQLCurrentTimeStamp( timeStampLong));
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Normal Time: "+getSQLCurrentTimeStamp());


        }

    public static java.sql.Timestamp getSQLCurrentTimeStamp(long timeStampLong)
    {
        Timestamp t2= new Timestamp(timeStampLong);
        return t2;
    }

     public static java.sql.Timestamp getSQLCurrentTimeStamp()
    {

        java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    Timestamp t= new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(t);
        return t;
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

All I want is to send the current time of the client PC to the server. I have tried both Javascript and Java inside JSP.

But there is an issue with the Javascript. I have my server in amazon EC2 US-West and I am in Sri Lanka. The time difference is +5.30GMT

When I deploy the code, the javascript simply gets the time of the server, not the time in my computer.

I tried using Java inside JSP and it is having another issue. That is, no matter where I place the `new Date.getTime()`, it is always getting the time the web page was loaded and it won't change even after minutes.

What am I doing here wrong? All I want is to send the current time of the client to the Server side Servlet.

Comment: Of course it will get the time of the server, because the users access your page on the server.

Comment: @drgPP: But there are lot of sites where it display the user's time correctly. For an example, try http://statcounter.com/

Comment: @drgPP: that depends how Tracer gets the timestamp. By doing it in JavaScript (so not the JSP inline tag) it should definitely be the client side timestamp.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet:

```
<%= new Date().getTime()%>
```

will always get the server time, so forget about using that.

To get the client timestamp you need to use JavaScript. In your HEAD section add this (within script tags of course):

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
}
```

This sets up the Date.now function in case the client uses Internet Explorer 8, which doesn't know Date.now

I don't know how JavaScript optimizes code. Maybe you could try this to see if it makes a difference if the Date is determined inside a function or not:

```
    <form action="TimestampClass" method="post" onsubmit="document.getElementById('hiddenTxt') = Date.now();">
        Name: <input type="text" name="nameTxt">
        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenTxt" id="hiddenTxt" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Now, how can I apply that `Date.now` inside the function to the HTML hidden field?

Comment: `Date.now` seems to display the server time again. For an example, toy can try dep[loying it in a server if you have one.

Comment: can you try to do ``alert(Date.now());``? I think you might be accidentally translating the client date when it is received by the server. If you do the alert, you will see the real client timestamp. If not, then I would be REALLY surprised. This is similar to @romapsih answer, but I mean it just to test sanity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JS function to get time

```
function time3(){
    alert(new Date().getTime());
}
```